# Asp.net webapi enum parameter with default value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, enums

I have a controller

```
   [HttpGet]
    [RoutePrefix("api/products/{productId}")] 
    public HttpResponseMessage Products(int productId,TypeEnum ptype=TypeEnum.Clothes)
{
    if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeOf(TypeEnum),ptype))
      //throw bad request exception
    else
      //continue processing
}
```

Myenum is declared as

```
public TypeEnum
{
  Clothes,
  Toys,
  Electronics
}
```

Currently if,some garbage value is passed it is getting converted into default value.
 What I want to do is if i call the controller as api/products/1 then the ptype should be assigned default value i.e clothes. If I call the controller as api/products/1?pType=somegarbagevalue then the controller should throw bad request exception. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do with `string` and use `TryParse()` to convert string to `Enum` value.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Products(int productId,string ptype="Clothes")
{
    TypeEnum category = TypeEnum.Clothes;
    if(!Enum.TryParse(ptype, true, out category))
      //throw bad request exception if you want. but it is fine to pass-through as default Cloathes value.
    else
      //continue processing
}
```

It may look naive but the benefit of this approach is to allow `ptype` parameter to  whatever string and to perform process without exception when `ptype` fails to bind the value.

Answer (score 14):

Defining all your enum parameters as strings and then parsing them everywhere means you have to do this on *every single action* and you will need to come up with a consistent approach such that all parsing errors conform.

This is a parameter binding issue and should not be dealt with in the controller layer, it should be taken care of in the pipeline. One way to do this is to create a custom filter and add it to your config.

```
public class ModelStateValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = <your standardised error response>
        }
    }
}
```

And in your global.asax.cs

```
...
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
...

public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...
        config.Filters.Add(new ModelStateValidationAttribute());
        ...
    }
}
```

If you're having trouble with the model state, it's type is a ModelStateDictionary and you simply iterate over it and then it's Errors property contains all the model binding issues. e.g.

```
modelState = actionContext.ModelState;
modelState.ForEach(x =>
        {
            var state = x.Value;
            if (state.Errors.Any())
            {
                foreach (var error in state.Errors)
                {
                    <work your magic>
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I do not quite understand this solution. Where is your code using/treating `TypeEnum` from the question? I have asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424564/jsonconverter-equivalent-for-http-get-parameter) that also links to yours.

Answer (score 0):

This type of validation should be handled in pipeline not in controller.

```
    public abstract class ETagMatchAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute
{
    private ETagMatch _match;

    public ETagMatchAttribute(ETagMatch match)
    {
        _match = match;
    }

    public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
    {
        if (parameter.ParameterType == typeof(ETag))
        {
            return new ETagParameterBinding(parameter, _match);
        }
        return parameter.BindAsError("Wrong parameter type");
    }
}
```

something like this. refer to [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) for detailed explanation