# JsonConverter equivalent for HTTP GET parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

When writing C# web API controllers for HTTP POST functions, I can use attributes from Newtonsoft JSON on the properties of the parameter object. In particular, I can use a [`JsonConverter` attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) on properties of an `enum` type to convert a string representation received from the client into one of the `enum` values (and back, for response objects):

```
public class MyArgumentsDTO
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SomeEnumConverter))]
    public SomeEnum MyValue { get; set; }
}

// in the controller:
[Route("doSomething")]
[HttpPost]
public Boolean DoSomething(MyArgumentsDTO options);
```

However, what should I do for HTTP GET methods that expect a parameter of such an `enum` type?

```
[Route("getSomething")]
[HttpGet]
public Boolean GetSomething(SomeEnum myValue);
```

**Is there an attribute that I can decorate the respective parameter with to indicate a (string to enum) converter?**

(To be clear, I am using enums as an example because I regularly use this technique (with HTTP POST) with enums. Presumeably, any solution that works for enums would just as well work for any other (possibly complex) data types.)

---

Of course, I could just declare the parameter as `string` and do the conversion myself, in the method body. However, that seems unclean, and I agree with a statement given in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29136301/1430156):

> Defining all your enum parameters as strings and then parsing them everywhere means you have to do this on *every single action* and you will need to come up with a consistent approach such that all parsing errors conform.

Unfortunately, I do not understand the solution proposed in that answer, given that it does not even touch upon using the `TypeEnum` mentioned in that question.

---

Using HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET for methods when I need an enum parameter seems somehow wrong, as well. I don't think the HTTP method should be chosen based upon such internal technicalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are correctly deserialized by ASP.NET model binder. Try defininig some simple enum, e.g.

```
public enum Color
{
    None,
    Green,
    Red,
}

[Route("getSomething")]
[HttpGet]
public string Get(Color color)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you GET `/api/values/color=Green`, color will be correctly set to `Color.Green`. If you need some custom values conversion (like `#FF0000` to `Color.Red`) approach with custom Type Converter (see below) will work for you.

ASP.NET also provides possibility to deserialize more complex data types from the url. The easiest way is to implement custom type converter. Here is a sample from the application I have developed some time ago. It worked with the orders that have unique identifiers in format `<department>:<order number>`, i.e. `NY:123` or `LA:456`. The model is

```
public class OrderId
{
    public string DepartmentId { get; }

    public int OrderNumber { get; }

    public OrderId(string departmentId, int orderNumber)
    {
        DepartmentId = departmentId;
        OrderNumber = orderNumber;
    }
}
```

And it was required to pass such order ids via HTTP GET method:

```
[HttpGet]
public OrderDetails GetOrderDetails(OrderId orderId)
```

To solve this and make `orderId` correctly created from an Url parameter, we could implement custom Type Converter that converts string value to instance of `OrderId`:

```
public class OrderIdTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    private static readonly Regex OrderIdRegex = new Regex("^(.+):(\\d+)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        if (str != null)
        {
            int orderId;
            var match = OrderIdRegex.Match(str);
            if (match.Success && Int32.TryParse(match.Groups[2].Value, out orderId))
            {
                return new OrderId(match.Groups[1].Value, orderId);
            }
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

To associate this Type Converter with OrderId class just add the `TypeConverter` attribute:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(OrderIdTypeConverter))]
public class OrderId
```

Now if we get Url `/api/Orders/?orderId=NYC:123`, action `GetOrderDetails` will be called with correctly filled instance of `OrderId`.

ASP.NET provides another extensibility points for binding the model from the URL. They are custom implementations of `IModelBinder` and `IValueProvider` interfaces. Check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) for more details.

If you can't set type converter for the type that you don't control, approach with custom model binder should work for you. Here is a sample of `IModelBinder` implementation for customizing conversion of enum values:

```
public class CustomEnumModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(Color))
        {
            return false;
        }

        ValueProviderResult val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (val == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string rawValue = val.RawValue as string;
        if (rawValue == null)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Incorrect input value type");
            return false;
        }

        //  Your logic for converting string to enum.
        if (rawValue == "FF0000")
        {
            bindingContext.Model = Color.Red;
            return true;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, $"Cannot convert {rawValue} to Color");
        return false;
    }
}

[Route("getSomething")]
[HttpGet]
public string Get([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomEnumModelBinder))] Color color)
{
    // ...
}
```

Wit a bit of additional work you could implement some sort of generic model binder that could aggregate your existing Json converters.

Comment: This looks definitely promising. One thing to note is that I do not want to use the automatic (de)serialization of enums and instead want to supply a custom mapping to custom strings. With that said, using the `TypeConverter` attribute on the type getting converted is problematic for me, as we are supposed to keep "inactive" definitions such as interfaces and enum types in one assembly that is referenced by another assembly, where I can define "active" things like converter classes. IOW, the type converter is not reachable from my enum type declaration. I'll read the linked article to see ...

Comment: ... whether it contains a solution for that issue.

Comment: There is a hack for assigning `TypeConverter` for types that you don't control: `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(Color), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ColorEnumConverter)))`

Comment: I have updated my answer with sample of model binder for custom enum conversion.

Comment: Excellent. It works with the model binder solution - from there, it should be easy enough for me to create a generic model binder that takes a type converter or offers a simple `StringToX` method or something to quickly adapt this pattern for other types.